# I'm having a bug with dictionaries Python 2.7

Tags: python, dictionary

The dictionary I made replaces letters with a dash(-) and two numbers.
In my dictionary, "t"="-21". And when I call "t" from the dictionary, I get "-21". But when I call `replace_all(text, dic)`, the output is "-2--5-63-5-63"
Any idea what's going wrong?

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:44:00) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ldic3 = {"a":"-02","b":"-03","c":"-04","d":"-05","e":"-06","f":"-07","g":"-08","h":"-09","i":"-10","j":"-11","k":"-12","l":"-13","m":"-14","n":"-15","o":"-16","p":"-17","q":"-18","r":"-19","s":"-20","t":"-21","u":"-22","v":"-23","w":"-24","x":"-25","y":"-26","z":"-27","A":"-28","B":"-29","C":"-30","D":"-31","E":"-32","F":"-33","G":"-34","H":"-35","I":"-36","J":"-37","K":"-38","L":"-39","M":"-40","N":"-41","O":"-42","P":"-43","Q":"-44","R":"-45","S":"-46","T":"-47","U":"-48","V":"-49","W":"-50","X":"-51","Y":"-52","Z":"-53","0":"-54","1":"-55","2":"-56","3":"-57","4":"-58","5":"-59","6":"-60","7":"-61","8":"-62","9":"-63"}
>>> def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text
#Example A
>>> var = "t"
>>> var2 = replace_all(var, ldic3)
>>> var2
'-2--5-63-5-63'
>>> ldic3["t"]
'-21'
#Example B
>>> var = "a"
>>> var2 = replace_all(var, ldic3)
>>> var2
'-02'
>>>
```

Quick edit:

This was meant to make the text unreadable, by changing the it over and over again. I can NOT turn my string into its own dictionary, without breaking my program. This is meant to change characters in entire paragraphs at a time.

Also, the code for "replace_all(text, dic)" is something I found online, and I'm not sure how it works.

Here is my program:

```
from Tkinter import *
import time

def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text

passchar = {"a":"0","b":"1","c":"2","d":"3","e":"0","f":"1","g":"2","h":"3","i":"0","j":"1","k":"2","l":"3","m":"0","n":"1","o":"2","p":"3","q":"0","r":"1","s":"2","t":"3","u":"0","v":"1","w":"2","x":"3","y":"0","z":"1"," ":""}
ldic0 = {"a":"-82","b":"-93","c":"-11","d":"-91","e":"-88","f":"-27","g":"-01","h":"-17","i":"-72","j":"-90","k":"-99","l":"-42","m":"-21","n":"-12","o":"-81","p":"-28","q":"-73","r":"-96","s":"-92","t":"-87","u":"-86","v":"-62","w":"-00","x":"-31","y":"-69","z":"-77","A":"-02","B":"-09","C":"-43","D":"-10","E":"-46","F":"-78","G":"-13","H":"-24","I":"-35","J":"-46","K":"-05","L":"-83","M":"-96","N":"-70","O":"-98","P":"-48","Q":"-29","R":"-32","S":"-52","T":"-94","U":"-53","V":"-66","W":"-44","X":"-51","Y":"-71","Z":"-80","0":"-97","1":"-39","2":"-26","3":"-54","4":"-22","5":"-07","6":"-40","7":"-30","8":"-50","9":"-60"}
ldic1 = {"a":"-01","b":"-02","c":"-03","d":"-04","e":"-05","f":"-06","g":"-07","h":"-08","i":"-09","j":"-10","k":"-11","l":"-12","m":"-13","n":"-14","o":"-15","p":"-16","q":"-17","r":"-18","s":"-19","t":"-20","u":"-21","v":"-22","w":"-23","x":"-24","y":"-25","z":"-26","A":"-27","B":"-28","C":"-29","D":"-30","E":"-31","F":"-32","G":"-33","H":"-34","I":"-35","J":"-36","K":"-37","L":"-38","M":"-39","N":"-40","O":"-41","P":"-42","Q":"-43","R":"-44","S":"-45","T":"-46","U":"-47","V":"-48","W":"-49","X":"-50","y":"-51","Z":"-52","0":"-53","1":"-54","2":"-55","3":"-56","4":"-57","5":"-58","6":"-59","7":"-60","8":"-61","9":"-62"}
ldic2 = {"a":"-02","b":"-03","c":"-04","d":"-05","e":"-06","f":"-07","g":"-08","h":"-09","i":"-10","j":"-11","k":"-12","l":"-13","m":"-14","n":"-15","o":"-16","p":"-17","q":"-18","r":"-19","s":"-20","t":"-21","u":"-22","v":"-23","w":"-24","x":"-25","y":"-26","z":"-27","A":"-28","B":"-29","C":"-30","D":"-31","E":"-32","F":"-33","G":"-34","H":"-35","I":"-36","J":"-37","K":"-38","L":"-39","M":"-40","N":"-41","O":"-42","P":"-43","Q":"-44","R":"-45","S":"-46","T":"-47","U":"-48","V":"-49","W":"-50","X":"-51","Y":"-52","Z":"-53","0":"-54","1":"-55","2":"-56","3":"-57","4":"-58","5":"-59","6":"-60","7":"-61","8":"-62","9":"-63"}
ldic3 = {"a":"-02","b":"-03","c":"-04","d":"-05","e":"-06","f":"-07","g":"-08","h":"-09","i":"-10","j":"-11","k":"-12","l":"-13","m":"-14","n":"-15","o":"-16","p":"-17","q":"-18","r":"-19","s":"-20","t":"-21","u":"-22","v":"-23","w":"-24","x":"-25","y":"-26","z":"-27","A":"-28","B":"-29","C":"-30","D":"-31","E":"-32","F":"-33","G":"-34","H":"-35","I":"-36","J":"-37","K":"-38","L":"-39","M":"-40","N":"-41","O":"-42","P":"-43","Q":"-44","R":"-45","S":"-46","T":"-47","U":"-48","V":"-49","W":"-50","X":"-51","Y":"-52","Z":"-53","0":"-54","1":"-55","2":"-56","3":"-57","4":"-58","5":"-59","6":"-60","7":"-61","8":"-62","9":"-63"}
#ldic3 = {"a":"-62","b":"-61","c":"-60","d":"-59","e":"-58","f":"-57","g":"-56","h":"-55","i":"-54","j":"-53","k":"-52","l":"-51","m":"-50","n":"-49","o":"-48","p":"-47","q":"-46","r":"-45","s":"-44","t":"-43","u":"-42","v":"-41","w":"-40","x":"-39","y":"-38","z":"-37","A":"-36","B":"-35","C":"-34","D":"-33","E":"-32","F":"-31","G":"-30","H":"-29","I":"-28","J":"-27","K":"-26","L":"-25","M":"-24","N":"-23","O":"-22","P":"-21","Q":"-20","R":"-19","S":"-18","T":"-17","U":"-16","V":"-15","W":"-14","X":"-13","Y":"-12","Z":"-10","0":"-09","1":"-08","2":"-07","3":"-06","4","-05","5":"-04","6":"-03","7":"-02","8":"-01","9":"-00"}

ndic0 = {"0":"3","1":"4","2":"1","3":"7","4":"9","5":"8","6":"2","7":"5","8":"6","9":"0"}
ndic1 = {"0":"1","1":"4","2":"3","3":"5","4":"0","5":"8","6":"2","7":"6","8":"9","9":"7"}
ndic2 = {"0":"2","1":"9","2":"8","3":"4","4":"7","5":"3","6":"0","7":"1","8":"6","9":"5"}
ndic3 = {"0":"4","1":"2","2":"3","3":"9","4":"0","5":"1","6":"7","7":"8","8":"6","9":"5"}


class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        #Initialize the frame
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.instruction = Label(self, text = "ENCRYPTION KEY:")
        self.instruction.grid(row = 0, column = 1, columnspan = 2, sticky = N) #sticky = direction W = West

        self.key = Entry(self) #Promps for user input
        self.key.grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky = N)

    #SPACER1
        self.spacer1 = Label(self, text = " ")
        self.spacer1.grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = N)

#-------------
    #ENCRYPT BUTTON
        self.encrypt_button = Button(self, width = 18, height = 2, text ="ENCRYPT", command = self.textboxa1)
        self.encrypt_button.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = N)

    #CLEAR BUTTON
        self.clear_button = Button(self, text ="CLEAR", width = 18, command = self.clearboxes)
        self.clear_button.grid(row = 3, column = 2, sticky = N)

    #DECRYPT BUTTON
        self.decrypt_button = Button(self, width = 18, height = 2, text ="DECRYPT",) #command = self.textboxa2
        self.decrypt_button.grid(row = 3, column = 3, sticky = N)

    #Top TextBox
        self.textbox1 = Text(self, width = 50, height = 15, wrap = WORD) # wrap = WORD CHAR or NONE
        self.textbox1.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 4, sticky = N)

#-------------
    #SPACER2
        self.spacer2 = Label(self, text = " ")
        self.spacer2.grid(row = 5, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = N)

    #Bottom TextBox
        self.textbox2 = Text(self, width = 50, height = 15, wrap = WORD)
        self.textbox2.grid(row = 6, column = 0, columnspan = 4, sticky = N)


    def textboxa1(self):
        keyvar = self.key.get()
        textvar = self.textbox1.get(0.0, END)
        keyvarl = len(keyvar)
        if keyvarl > 25 or keyvarl < 3:
            self.textbox2.delete(0.0, END)
            self.textbox2.insert(0.0, '"' + keyvar + '"' + " -ERROR PASSWORD MUST BE 3 - 25 CHARACTERS LONG")
        else:
            step = 0
            num = 0
            passcode = replace_all(keyvar, passchar)
            #self.textbox2.delete(0.0, END)
            #self.textbox2.insert(0.0, "start")
            for i in range(keyvarl):
                char = list(passcode)
                dig = passcode[num]
                self.textbox2.insert(0.0, "")
                if dig == "0":
                    if step == 0:
                        step = 1
                        textvar2 = replace_all(textvar, ldic0)
                        #time.sleep(0.5)
                        #self.textbox2.insert(0.0, "0")
                    else:
                        textvar2 = replace_all(textvar2, ndic0)
                        #time.sleep(0.5)
                        #self.textbox2.insert(0.0, "0")
                elif dig == "1":
                    if step == 0:
                        step = 1
                        textvar2 = replace_all(textvar, ldic1)
                        #time.sleep(0.5)
                        #self.textbox2.insert(0.0, "1")
                    else:
                        textvar2 = replace_all(textvar2, ndic1)
                        #time.sleep(0.5)
                        #self.textbox2.insert(0.0, "1")
                elif dig == "2":
                    if step == 0:
                        step = 1
                        textvar2 = replace_all(textvar, ldic2)
                        #time.sleep(0.5)
                        #self.textbox2.insert(0.0, "2")
                    else:
                        textvar2 = replace_all(textvar2, ndic2)
                        #time.sleep(0.5)
                        #self.textbox2.insert(0.0, "2")
                else:
                    if step == 0:
                        step = 1
                        textvar2 = replace_all(textvar, ldic3)
                        #time.sleep(0.5)
                        #self.textbox2.insert(0.0, "3")
                    else:
                        textvar2 = replace_all(textvar2, ndic3)
                        #time.sleep(0.5)
                        #self.textbox2.insert(0.0, "3")
                keyvar2 = keyvarl - 1
                if i == keyvar2:
                    #self.textbox2.delete(0.0, END)
                    self.textbox2.insert(0.0, textvar2 + textvar)
                else:
                    #self.textbox2.delete(0.0, END)
                    self.textbox2.insert(0.0, textvar2 + textvar)
                    self.textbox2.insert(0.0, keyvar2)
                    self.textbox2.insert(0.0, " of ")
                    self.textbox2.insert(0.0, num)
                    self.textbox2.insert(0.0, "Step: ")
                   # self.textbox2.insert(0.0, textvar2 + textvar)
                num = num + 1



   # def textboxa2(self):
       # input1 = self.key.get()
       # input2 = self.textbox1.get(0.0, END)

       # self.textbox2.delete(0.0, END)
       # self.textbox2.insert(0.0, input1 + input2)

    def clearboxes(self):
        self.textbox1.delete(0.0, END)
        self.textbox2.delete(0.0, END)









root = Tk()
root.title("FirePie Demo - Message Encryptor!")
root.geometry("403x630")
app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The replaceall is actually the problem. It's iterating over item in the dictionary. I would recommend learning how you iterate over elements in a dictionary (by key, by values, or by items) so you can understand why the code breaks.

The issue is that you replace a value, and then you can use the replaced value again as a input before the loop is finished. The code is also very inefficient, since you loop over the full dictionary, rather than just each character in the string you are changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"t" is replaced with "-21"

Then "1" is replaced with "-55"

Then both "5"s are replaced with "-59", resulting in "-2--59-59"

Then both "9"s are replaced with "-63", resulting in "-2--5-63-5-63", which is returned.

If you want to not replace letters produced by one of the previous replacements, consider replacing letters one at at time:

```py
def replace_all(text, dic):
    return ''.join(dic.get(x, x) for x in text)
```

The second `x` in `get` here is the default value in case `dict` doesn't have key `x`.

Comment: '"".join(sequence) can use a generator comprehension, there's no to form the list first, then join the sequence.

"".join(dict[x] for x in dic else x for x in text) works just as well.

Comment: This could also be `return ''.join(dic.get(x, x) for x in text)`.

Comment: This did work, but could you please explain to me what each part does and how?

Comment: `[do_something for x in x]` is identical to `ret = []; for x in x: ret.append(do_something(x))`. So `[dic.get(x, x) for x in test]` computes a list that has as many elements as `test` and each element is the mapping from your dictionary for the corresponding letter. Finally, `''.join([])` converts a list of letters into a string.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh Actually, it's faster to use a list instead of a generator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060653/list-comprehension-without-python/9061024#9061024

Comment: Good to know, I just benchmarked @TerryA, and I can't believe it, but I guess it makes sense....

Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overcomplicating this way too much. You're trying to replace a string with something that doesn't exist too many times before what you really want to do occurs.

Try this:

```
def replace_all(text, dic):
    return ''.join([dic[i] for i in text])
```

Answer (score 1):

I've added a couple print statements to show what's happening.

```
>>> def replace_all(text, dic):
    print text
    for i, j in dic.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
        print "i: %s, j: %s, text: %s" % (i,j,text)
    return text

>>> var2 = replace_all(var, ldic3)
t
i: 0, j: -54, text: t
i: 2, j: -56, text: t
i: 4, j: -58, text: t
i: 6, j: -60, text: t
i: 8, j: -62, text: t
i: B, j: -29, text: t
i: D, j: -31, text: t
i: F, j: -33, text: t
i: H, j: -35, text: t
i: J, j: -37, text: t
i: L, j: -39, text: t
i: N, j: -41, text: t
i: P, j: -43, text: t
i: R, j: -45, text: t
i: T, j: -47, text: t
i: V, j: -49, text: t
i: X, j: -51, text: t
i: Z, j: -53, text: t
i: b, j: -03, text: t
i: d, j: -05, text: t
i: f, j: -07, text: t
i: h, j: -09, text: t
i: j, j: -11, text: t
i: l, j: -13, text: t
i: n, j: -15, text: t
i: p, j: -17, text: t
i: r, j: -19, text: t
i: t, j: -21, text: -21
i: v, j: -23, text: -21
i: x, j: -25, text: -21
i: z, j: -27, text: -21
i: 1, j: -55, text: -2-55
i: 3, j: -57, text: -2-55
i: 5, j: -59, text: -2--59-59
i: 7, j: -61, text: -2--59-59
i: 9, j: -63, text: -2--5-63-5-63
i: A, j: -28, text: -2--5-63-5-63
i: C, j: -30, text: -2--5-63-5-63
i: E, j: -32, text: -2--5-63-5-63
i: G, j: -34, text: -2--5-63-5-63
i: I, j: -36, text: -2--5-63-5-63
i: K, j: -38, text: -2--5-63-5-63
i: M, j: -40, text: -2--5-63-5-63
i: O, j: -42, text: -2--5-63-5-63
i: Q, j: -44, text: -2--5-63-5-63
i: S, j: -46, text: -2--5-63-5-63
i: U, j: -48, text: -2--5-63-5-63
i: W, j: -50, text: -2--5-63-5-63
i: Y, j: -52, text: -2--5-63-5-63
i: a, j: -02, text: -2--5-63-5-63
i: c, j: -04, text: -2--5-63-5-63
i: e, j: -06, text: -2--5-63-5-63
i: g, j: -08, text: -2--5-63-5-63
i: i, j: -10, text: -2--5-63-5-63
i: k, j: -12, text: -2--5-63-5-63
i: m, j: -14, text: -2--5-63-5-63
i: o, j: -16, text: -2--5-63-5-63
i: q, j: -18, text: -2--5-63-5-63
i: s, j: -20, text: -2--5-63-5-63
i: u, j: -22, text: -2--5-63-5-63
i: w, j: -24, text: -2--5-63-5-63
i: y, j: -26, text: -2--5-63-5-63
```

So you see, it correctly finds `t` and replaces it with `-21`. Oh, but then it also finds `1` and replaces that with `-55`. And then both `5`s get replaced with `-59`. And finally, both `9`s get replaced with `-63`. For solutions, [TerryA's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33979738/1473772) and [Ishmael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33979741/1473772) both look good.

Answer (score 1):

Just `map()` it to the dictionary with the `get()` method.

```
result = ''.join(map(ldic3.get, var))
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a bug. You have to remember that 't' will not be the first, nor the last item in the dict iteration.

I edited your code to trace the error:

```
def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.iteritems():
        text2 = text.replace(i, j)
        if text2 != text:
            print(i)
            text = text2
    return text
```

It prints out the following

```
t
1
5
9
```

You have to consider the possible errors in your code when you are constructing it here: here you want to replace only "t", not everything after a replace event has occurred.

This means, it first replaces "t" with "-21", then "1" with "-55", and so forth. You might want to add a break statement, or explicitly change **1** value.

Comment: this is a message encryptor, it will me replacing paragraphs at a time.. but the bug only seems to happen with the letter "t"

Comment: You can then iterate over the items in the text, character-by-character, and then join them at the end (as described above) so you do not accidentally re-feed the output back into the input. See @tigerhawk's solution for the most idiomatic solution.